# Ошибка в задачке С#

Tags: c#, массивы

Возникла проблема, помогите пожалуйста ее решить "system.indexoutofrangeexception". Ошибка возникает здесь:

```
Console.WriteLine("Массив с нечетного ряда чисел: ");
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    Console.Write(" {0}", b[i]); (ЗДЕСЬ!)
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить.Нужно чтобы из исходного массива остались только те цифры, что стоят на нечетных местах(1,3,5,7,9 и т.д)

```
using System;

 namespace tapsyrma
 {
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i, k,y=0;
        int[] a = new int[30];
        int[] b = new int[(a.Length + 1) / 2];
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Исходный массив: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            a[i] = rnd.Next(-50, 51);
            Console.Write(" {0}", a[i]);
        }

        for (i = 0; i <30; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] % 2 != 0) y++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (i = 0, k = 0; i < b.Length; i++, k+=2)
        {
            b[i] = a[k];
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Массив с нечетного ряда чисел: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            Console.Write(" {0}", b[i]);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас массив `b` определен как

```
int[] b = new int[(a.Length + 1) / 2];
```

то есть он имеет 15 элементов согласно определению массива `a`

```
int[] a = new int[30];
```

Однако в этом цикле

```
   for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        Console.Write(" {0}", b[i]);
```

вы используете индекс за пределами допустимого диапазон индексов для массива `b`.

По крайней мере вы могли бы записать

```
   for (i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(" {0}", b[i]);
```

Имейте в виду, что в условии задания вы написали, что

> Нужно чтобы из исходного массива остались только те цифры, что **стоят
>   на нечетных местах**

а в данном цикле

```
    for (i = 0; i <30; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] % 2 != 0) y++;
    }
```

подсчитываете, сколько элементов массива имеют четные значения. При этом переменная `y` далее нигде не используется.